# FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME and WriteFile fail

Tags: c#, powershell, winapi, pinvoke

I've created a small app to make backups of disks and to restore a disk from a backup. The logic is pretty simple:

- Call `CreateFile` on `\\.\PhysicalDrive<index>`
- Do the same for destination physical drive
- Call `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` on source + destination handles
- Call `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME` on source + destination handles
- In a loop, use `ReadFile` to read from source and write it to destination using `WriteFile` until all bytes have been written.
- Call `DeviceIoControl` with `FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME` on both source and destination handles
- Call `CloseHandle` on both source and destination handles

I always check that all operations are successful before continuing to the next call. This works really well, but I noticed something that is a bit puzzling:

If, while a copy is taking place, the OS tries to do something with the physical disk (which *I know* is locked) then the next `WriteFile` fails.

Examples of things that cause this to fail:

- Removing a separate disk (like removing a USB stick not used as either the source or the destination)
- Opening disk management
- In PowerShell, doing `Get-Disk`

Those things all cause the very next `WriteFile` call to fail, and I have no idea why. According to the documentation I read `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` should prevent any other process from acquiring a handle to the disk, so I can't understand why those things could cause issues on a locked volume. Can anyone elaborate and provide a way around it?

Here's my code: it's written in PowerShell but it could easily be converted to C# or something similar.

```
function Start-RawCopy
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='FileAndFile')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='FileAndDisk')]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $SourceFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='DiskAndFile')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='DiskAndDisk')]
        [UInt16]
        $SourceDiskNumber,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='FileAndFile')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='DiskAndFile')]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]
        $DestinationFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='FileAndDisk')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName, ParameterSetName='DiskAndDisk')]
        [UInt16]
        $DestinationDiskNumber
    )

    Begin
    {
        $FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME = 0x00090018
        $FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME = 0x0009001c
        $FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME = 0x00090020

        $DELETE = 0x00010000
        $READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000
        $WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000
        $WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000
        $SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000
        $STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000
        $STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = $READ_CONTROL
        $STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = $READ_CONTROL
        $STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = $READ_CONTROL
        $FILE_READ_DATA = 0x0001  # file & pipe
        $FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001  # directory
        $FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x0002  # file & pipe
        $FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x0002  # directory
        $FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x0004  # file
        $FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x0004  # directory
        $FILE_CREATE_PIPE_INSTANCE = 0x0004  # named pipe
        $FILE_READ_EA = 0x0008  # file & directory
        $FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x0010  # file & directory
        $FILE_EXECUTE = 0x0020  # file
        $FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x0020  # directory
        $FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x0040  # directory
        $FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080  # all
        $FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0100  # all

        $FILE_ALL_ACCESS = $STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED -bor $SYNCHRONIZE -bor 0x1FF
        $FILE_GENERIC_READ = $STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ -bor $FILE_READ_DATA -bor $FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES -bor $FILE_READ_EA -bor $SYNCHRONIZE
        $FILE_GENERIC_WRITE = $STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE -bor $FILE_WRITE_DATA -bor $FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES -bor $FILE_WRITE_EA -bor $FILE_APPEND_DATA -bor $SYNCHRONIZE
        $FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE = $STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE -bor $FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES -bor $FILE_EXECUTE -bor $SYNCHRONIZE

        $FILE_SHARE_DELETE = 0x00000004
        $FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x00000001
        $FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 0x00000002

        $CREATE_NEW = 1
        $CREATE_ALWAYS = 2
        $OPEN_EXISTING = 3
        $OPEN_ALWAYS = 4
        $TRUNCATE_EXISTING = 5

        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
    }

    Process
    {
        # Validate parameters        
        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SourceFile'))
        {
            if (!$SourceFile.Exists)
            {
                throw "Source file does not exist, cannot continue"
            }

            $source = $SourceFile.FullName
        }
        else 
        {
            $source = "\\.\PhysicalDrive$SourceDiskNumber"
        }

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DestinationFile'))
        {
            $destination = $DestinationFile.FullName
            $creationDisposition = $CREATE_ALWAYS
        }
        else 
        {
            $destination = "\\.\PhysicalDrive$DestinationDiskNumber"
            $creationDisposition = $OPEN_EXISTING
        }

        try 
        {
            # Start process
            Write-Warning "Starting raw copy - $(Get-Date)"

            # Open source object
            $handleSource = [NativeMethods]::CreateFile($source, $FILE_GENERIC_READ, $FILE_SHARE_READ -bor $FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, $OPEN_EXISTING, 0, [IntPtr]::Zero)

            if (!$handleSource)
            {
                throw "Failed to open source object to read"
            }

            # Clean destination volume
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DestinationDiskNumber'))
            {
                Get-Disk -Number $DestinationDiskNumber | Get-Partition | Remove-Partition -Confirm:$false
                # Without a sleep this will fail on the 5th WriteFile call all the time. Some caching issue?
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
            }

            # Open destination object
            $handleDestination = [NativeMethods]::CreateFile($destination, $FILE_ALL_ACCESS, $FILE_SHARE_READ -bor $FILE_SHARE_WRITE -bor $FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 0, $creationDisposition, 0, [IntPtr]::Zero)

            if (!$handleDestination)
            {
                throw "Failed to open destination object to write"
            }

            $i = 0

            # Lock and dismount source volume
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SourceDiskNumber'))
            {
                if (![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleSource, $FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to lock source volume"
                }

                if (![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleSource, $FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to dismount source volume"
                }
            }

            # Lock and dismount destination volume
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DestinationDiskNumber'))
            {
                if (![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleDestination, $FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to lock destination volume"
                }

                if (![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleDestination, $FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to dismount destination volume"
                }
            }

            # Get source size
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SourceDiskNumber'))
            {
                $sourceSize = (Get-CimInstance -Namespace ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage -Class MSFT_Disk -Filter "Number = $SourceDiskNumber").Size
            }
            else
            {
                $sourceSize = $SourceFile.Length
            }

            $buffer = [Byte[]]::new(32MB)
            $bytesRead = [UInt32] 0
            $bytesWritten = [UInt32] 0
            [UInt64] $totalBytesRead = 0

            # Copy data
            do
            {
                if ($totalBytesRead + $buffer.Length -gt $sourceSize)
                {
                    $buffer = [Byte[]]::new($sourceSize - $totalBytesRead)

                    if ($Validate)
                    {
                        $verifyBuffer = [Byte[]]::new($buffer.Length)
                    }
                }

                if (![NativeMethods]::ReadFile($handleSource, $buffer, $buffer.Length, [ref] $bytesRead, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to read from source"
                }

                if (![NativeMethods]::WriteFile($handleDestination, $buffer, $bytesRead, [ref] $bytesWritten, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to write to destination"
                }

                if ($bytesRead -ne $bytesWritten)
                {
                    throw "Read $bytesRead bytes but only wrote $bytesWritten bytes"
                }

                $totalBytesRead += $bytesRead                
            } until ($totalBytesRead -eq $sourceSize)
        }
        finally
        {
            # Unlock source volume
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('SourceDiskNumber'))
            {
                if ($handleSource -and ![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleSource, $FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to unlock source volume"
                }
            }

            # Unlock destination volume
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DestinationDiskNumber'))
            {
                if ($handleDestination -and ![NativeMethods]::DeviceIoControl($handleDestination, $FSCTL_UNLOCK_VOLUME, $null, 0, $null, 0, [ref] $i, [IntPtr]::Zero))
                {
                    throw "Failed to unlock destination volume"
                }
            }

            # Close source handle
            if ($handleSource -and ![NativeMethods]::CloseHandle($handleSource))
            {
                throw "Failed to close source object"
            }

            # Close destination handle
            if ($handleDestination -and ![NativeMethods]::CloseHandle($handleDestination))
            {
                throw "Failed to close destination object"
            }
            Write-Warning "Ended raw copy - $(Get-Date)"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if some api call is fail - begin from call `GetLastError` and (much better here) `RtlGetLastNtStatus`

Comment: @RbMm forgot to add, the error is `ERROR_WRITE_FAULT`, which is just a generic 'couldn't write'. The question however is why would opening disk management for example would cause it to fail in the first place, bearing in mind the disk is locked.

Comment: please call `RtlGetLastNtStatus` instead - which status it return ? after first fail. which api call **first** fail ? and which `NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlGetLastNtStatus()` after this ?

Comment: Can't find info to create the PInvoke for `RtlGetLastNtStatus`. The call that fails is to `WriteFile`.

Comment: `RtlGetLastNtStatus` have the same signature as `GetLastError`. simply call it. so you say that first fail api `WriteFile` ? not `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` ? the first fail call is key point. and `RtlGetLastNtStatus`